# WordPress Custom Field conditional based on postmeta value

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I've got a chunk of code that's working fine, but I need to alter it.

It works but only if there's a value in the DB.  If not, it produces a value of 0.0 which is ok...but I want it to say "N/A" as opposed to 0.0.

How would I alter the following block of code so it would display a value of "N/A" if the value was 0.0 and otherwise function as it already does?

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
if( get_post_meta($postid, 'Rankextras', true))  {
echo '<span class="skill-bg" data-percent=" ' . get_post_meta($postid, 'Rankextras', true) . '%" style="width: ' . get_post_meta($postid, 'Rankextras', true) . '%">    </span><span class="skill-name">  Extras</span><span class="skill-progress">' . get_post_meta($postid, 'Rankextras', true) . '</span>'; 
}
?>
```

Comment: "I've got a chunk of code that's working fine" ok then, moving on to next question.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is already going to return an empty string if the metadata does not exist. Based on the code that you posted, could it be that there is some javascript that formats empty data-percent attributes to be 0.0?

Comment: Here's a working example, maybe it'll make a bit more sense if I show what I'm trying to accomplish.

http://blurayauthority.com/game/skylanders-swap-force-xbox-one/

Note the "Extras" says 0.0 because it's a video game and, therefore, has no extras.  Maybe that'll clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (modify the block where it echos 'N/A' to your needs):

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$value = get_post_meta($postid, 'Rankextras', true);
if(!$value OR $value == '0.0')
{
    echo 'N/A';
}
else
{
    echo '<span class="skill-bg" data-percent=" ' . $value . '%" style="width: ' . $value . '%">    </span><span class="skill-name">  Extras</span><span class="skill-progress">' . $value . '</span>'; 
}
```

I also refactored your code a bit, so it uses less queries.